# Sqlite3 NodeJs redirect when login

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a requirement where the user is supposed to get redirect to a welcome page if the login is a success whereas the user should get an error message when the login is failed.

I am able to print the data in the console but I just need some help in redirecting the user to a webpage on success and failure.

below is the app.js function through which i am able to print on console

```
app.post('/loginform', function (req, res, next) {

    let sql = `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username  = ? and Password = ?`;
    let Username = `${req.body.name}`;
    let Password = `${req.body.password}`;
    let success;

    db.get(sql, [Username, Password], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
        }
        return row
        ? console.log(`Login Success `+ row.ID, row.Username,row.Password)
        : console.log(`Sorry, your username and password are incorrect. Try again!`);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to print what's returning as row and based on the values, I understood that it returns undefined when the login fails and it returns a json data of that user row when login success.

So I came up with the below solution.

```
db.get(sql, [Username, Password], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log(row);
        if(row != undefined){
            res.redirect('/welcome.html');
        }
        else{
            res.write('<html><body>');
            res.write('<h1>Sorry your username and password are incorrect. Try again!</h1>');
            res.write('</body></html>');
            res.send();
        }
    });
```